# Footer not displayed properly on mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile, footer, html

I'm working on my portfolio website, and ran into a problem when viewing it on a mobile browser. Here is the website: http://attilakomaromi.ca/so_question/

If you scroll down, you'll notice that the footer is revealed. Chrome's mobile emulators also display the footer properly. However, when viewing the webpage on an actual smartphone, the footer can be scrolled to, but the page will snap back up the hide it once you remove your finger from the screen (please take a look at the above link on your phones to understand this problem).

Here is the repository on GitHub for my website, if you need to take a closer look at the code: https://github.com/Twinbird24/portfolio-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css and then try

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    footer {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does fix the issue of the footer disappearing, but now I lost the "reveal" effect of the footer that I have in the full-size webpage. Perhaps I'll have to live with this trade-off though, because I know of no other way.

Comment: Yup.  I guess so.

Comment: You can play with the static position to get that effect.